# Autocomplete using jquery in wordpress not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, wordpress, autocomplete

I am using wordpress and I want to have a search textbox that would autocomplete upon keychange. The results for the autocomplete should come from the database that contains the product names.

Here's what I have but it's not working. Nothing shows up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#product").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.getJSON("../searchProduct.php"){
            term: $(#product).val()
        }, response);
    }
});
```

on searchProduct.php, I have:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
require_once('/wp-config.php');

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$searchTerm = esc_sql($searchTerm);
$searchTerm = like_escape($searchTerm);

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_products WHERE productName LIKE '".$searchTerm."%'");     
    foreach ( $results as $products ) {
        $data[] = $products->productName;
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

What could be the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you look in the Network tab in the Developer Tools in Chrome (or equivalent in FireFox) can you see the ajax call? Is it returning a 200 Status? Is there a response?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what exactly the issue is without some error information. If you inspect, what is the response code? 404? 500?

One thing I notice is that you are using `$(document).ready(function() {`, and Wordpress requires no-conflict jQuery wrappers. Try switching that line out for `jQuery(function($) {`

Here is some more info if you need it: http://wptricks.net/jquery-noconflict-wrappers-on-wordpress/